# Find the expectation of this mass function

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, power-series, expected-value

$p_x$ is defined as follows:\begin{cases}
          \dfrac{2^x}{(e^2-1)x!} \quad &\text{if} \, x =1,2,3,\dots \\
          0 \quad &\text{if} \, o/w \\
     \end{cases}

Find $E(X)$.

$$E(X)=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}xp_x==\frac{1}{e^2-1}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{x*2^x}{x!}=\frac{2}{e^2-1}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{x-1}}{(x-1)!}$$

I don't know how to evaluate the series.

Wolfram tells me that the series alone (not the constants on the outside) evaluates to $e^2$

Is there some sort of trick to see this?

Comment: The series is $e^2 - 1$, because it's the Taylor series of $e^x - 1$ evaluated at $x = 2$.

Comment: What happened to the $x$ in $x p_x$?

Comment: @platty sorry i fixed it and revised my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-index the final sum to get:
$$
E(X) = \frac{2}{e^2 - 1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!}
$$
As mentioned in @T. Bongers' comment, this summation is just the evaluation of the Taylor series $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ at $x = 2$. So we get:
$$
E(X) = \frac{2e^2}{e^2 - 1}
$$